# Check for calling activity or call setResult anyway

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have two Activities. One extends Fragment activity and displays some data in a list (fragment1) and details if one clicks on a list item (fragment2). Fragment2 has a menu item that can be clicked to edit that data set. If the user wants to edit the data fragment2 calls the other activity per `startActivityForResult` in which he can edit the data set.

Should I check in the edit activity if it was invoked for a result by `getCallingActivity` or should I `setResult` anyway? (I `finish()` the activity after saving to restart the activity in order to clear the `EditText` views, since one can edit or insert new data sets in that activity.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead and just call `setResult()` without checking the calling Activity.  The Activity that doesn't care about the result will simply ignore it with no harm done.